# facing issues for genarating 11 hash key string which is provide on official documentation on SMS Retriever API

Tags: android, sms, google-play-services, smsmanager, one-time-password

my apk is working fine in debug mode. but when I signed apk with release mode then
automatic sms retrivr is not working.

then I search I found I have to generate a hash key on official documentation 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#generating_a_one-time_code

where I found two methods
1> by signature helped class- I used but not working
2> second by following command

keytool -exportcert -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11

but I got xxd command is not found

then I search on the stack then i run a command on git bash command runs but that hash key still not working

Answer (score 4):

It would be easier to generate hash through this code.

Just call below line and print your signature.

`ArrayList<String> sigList = (new AppSignatureHelper(this)).getAppSignatures()`

Code Reference: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java

**Update:**

Hash code for debug and release version will be different.
Make sure you are using release specific app hash code for otp message with required format.

AppSignatureHelper will provide hash code using which apk is signed. Build release apk and print hash code in log to get release specific hash code.

**Update:**

Another approach of generating through command mentioned in : https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string

However if you are using windows, it may not work as you it dont have binary (command) like xxd or tr.
in that case, you have to download those exe from somewhere else.

If you are using git then you can find them at "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\", in that case follow this steps.

1. Add path "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\" in your environment variables.
2. Restart your command prompt. so xxd and tr starts working in prompt.
3. apply mentioned command in link.

`keytool -exportcert -alias MY_ANDROID_KEY -keystore MY_PRODUCTION_KEY | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n MY_PACKAGE_NAME`cat`| sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11`

Where in command

- replace MY_ANDROID_KEY with your key alias
- replace MY_PRODUCTION_KEY with your keystore path (some xyz.jks)
- replace MY_PACKAGE_NAME with your package name

  4. you will get 11 character long hash key. Hurray.

Here, if you are facing error like `tr: write error: Illegal seek`,
you can call cammand up to tr like ->

`keytool -exportcert -alias MY_ANDROID_KEY -keystore MY_PRODUCTION_KEY | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]"`

in this case you will get around 1800+ character long signature string. 
pass package and signature string to hash method of AppSignatureHelper, it will return your key.

(Here, If at the end you are using `AppSignatureHelper`, i suggest to go for that first approach only)

Comment: i alraedy mentioned that i used that class but still you r copy and paste the class first read my question

Comment: What you meant by signature helper class code not working. Code for debug and release app will be different. Make sure you are using release app hash code in otp message.

Comment: thanks but can you send me both different links for debug and release mode of that class . as i searched there is no any specific class for release and debug mode..

Comment: no need. It will read from the signature using which apk is signed. Print that code in log after building apk with release mode.

Comment: bro i had already used,  hash key is same as when is signed apk in debug and release mode .and how  android studio knows about apk it only knows code. what impact on debug or release mode. apk is totally different

Comment: If you are getting same hashcode in both version, then may be you are not generating your release apk properly with release keystore. Hashcode for debug and release can't be same.

Comment: apk is totally different thing suppose i had generated signed apk correctly then how android stuido runs signature helper class according to debug or release mode.as i know android studio hasnt any imapact about relase or debug apk it only compile or run code.

Comment: [Continue this discussion here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188727/discussion-for-apk-signature-related-info)

Comment: means according to you first i have to generated signed apk and then i have to install that signed apk on phone and then connected that phone to android studio using usb and then print log i did . but same hash string

Comment: @indrajeetjyoti May be release apk is not built properly then. Check updated answer if it can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AppSignatureHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    private static final String TAG = "AppSignatureHelper";
    private static final String HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
    public static final int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
    public static final int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

    public AppSignatureHelper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Get all the app signatures for the current package
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getAppSignatures() {
        ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            // Get all package signatures for the current package
            String packageName = getPackageName();
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

            // For each signature create a compatible hash
            for (Signature signature : signatures) {
                String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
                if (hash != null) {
                    appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash));
                }
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e);
        }
        return appCodes;
    }

    private static String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
        String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
            messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();

            // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
            hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
            // encode into Base64
            String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
            base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);

            CommonUtils.base64Val = base64Hash;
            Log.e("base64Val",base64Hash);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, base64Hash));
            return base64Hash;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can use base64hash for debug build and if you are making app live, make signed APK and use the value generated from signed APK.

Don't forget to call this class from main application's oncreate()

```
 AppSignatureHelper appSignatureHelper = new AppSignatureHelper(this);
    appSignatureHelper.getAppSignatures();
```

Comment: how you generate value from signed apk

Comment: and key generate from above code is not used fro sms reterver api. thanks for suggestion

Comment: Hi Indrajeet, I have used SMS retriever API in my app and use the same value generated from the above code and uploaded the application on the play store and it is working perfectly.

Comment: its not possible sms retervier hash key generation alogrithm is totally diffrent

Comment: refer this document

Comment: There are multiple ways to generate that. Refer to this blog. https://androidwave.com/automatic-sms-verification-android/